# стоит ли читать книги по winApi(с++) бывалой давности

Tags: c++, winapi

Здраствуйте, решил начать изучать winApi с помощью книг. Но зайдя на множество форумов где советуют
книги по winApi встречаются книги которым уже прилично много лет, типа книг Рихтера или Петцольда. Устарела ли в них информация или все еще можно изучать их?

Comment: вам лучше задавать такие вопросы на тех форумах, где вы это видели. тематика данного сайта другая - помогать с кодом. 99.999% что такой вопрос закроют.

Comment: @homer Авторы актуальны. Это все таки api ОС.

Comment: WinAPI ещё больше лет, чем этим книгам. Если и были какие-то изменения, Вы найдёте их на MSDN. Думаю, общая суть с тех лет не изменилась. Но на всякий случай лучше добавьте в вопрос годы издания книг.